# java program for evaluating postfix expression results in numberformat exception in one of the methods leetcode #150 for stack.Suggest changes please

Tags: java, exception, data-structures, stack

```
class Solution {
     public boolean isoperand(String ch)
        {
            return(Integer.parseInt(ch)>=0 && Integer.parseInt(ch)<=9) ;
             
        }
     public int operate(String ch,int a,int b)
        {
            switch(ch){
                case "*":return a*b;
                case "/":return a/b;
                case "+":return a+b;
                case "-":return a-b;
                
            }
         return 0;
        }
    public int evalRPN(String[] tokens) {
    Stack<String> st=new Stack<>();
       
       
        int l=tokens.length;
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            if(isoperand(tokens[i]))
                st.push(tokens[i]);
            else{
                int b=Integer.parseInt(st.pop());
                int a=Integer.parseInt(st.pop());
                int result=operate(tokens[i],a,b);
                st.push(Integer.toString(result));
            }
            
            
        }
        
        
            int temp=Integer.parseInt(st.pop());
        
        return temp;
        
    }
}
```

this is my program to implement evaluation of postfix expression in stack.
Can anyone help me? i get a numberformat exception when the method isoperand is executed. i am fairly new to java.

Comment: parseInt works only on valid integers, so as used here in `isoperand`, it's useless for determining whether something is a valid integer.  Either rewrite that to use some other way to check for an integer, or catch the exception.

Comment: But you could use ```ch.charAt(0)>='0' && ch.charAt(0)<='9'``` if you want to stick with the original approach. You'd still have to check that ```ch``` is actually a one character string though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `isoperand` returns true only if the number lies between 0 and 9, which is not the case. We have numbers that are greater than 9 as well. Hence it results in RuntimeError.
So, it's always better to check if the current token is an `operator`, if not then it must be an `operand`.
I've used a set to efficiently check if the current token is an operator or not by adding all operators: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` to the set.
Here is an improved version of your code:

```
class Solution
{
    public int operate(String ch, int a, int b)
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
            case "*": return a*b;
            case "/": return a/b;
            case "+": return a+b;
            case "-": return a-b; 
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int evalRPN(String[] tokens)
    {
        Set<String> operators = new HashSet<>();
        operators.add("*"); operators.add("/");
        operators.add("+"); operators.add("-");
        
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
        int len = tokens.length;
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            if (operators.contains(tokens[i]))
            {
                int b = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                int a = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
                int result = operate(tokens[i], a, b);
                stack.push(Integer.toString(result));
            }
            else
                stack.push(tokens[i]);
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(stack.pop());
    }
}
```

**Runtime: 4 ms, faster than 88.95% of Java submissions**